# How to indent output json files in haskell

Tags: json, haskell

- Can Haskell **indent output json files** so it is **human friendly**?
- This option exists in other programming languages (like Python)
- Listed below is a working example for:

  - reading an input json file
  - manipulating it somehow
  - storing back the results to another json file
- Only trouble is, I can *not* humanly inspect it, because it is a huge one-liner

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

-- ***************
-- *             *
-- * module main *
-- *             *
-- ***************
module Main (main) where

-- *******************
-- *                 *
-- * general imports *
-- *                 *
-- *******************
import System.IO  
import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment

-- *****************************
-- *                           *
-- * general qualified imports *
-- *                           *
-- *****************************
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

-- ****************************
-- *                          *
-- * read json file to memory *
-- *                          *
-- ****************************
getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = B.readFile "input.json"

-- *********************
-- *                   *
-- * data type: Person *
-- *                   *
-- *********************
data Person =
  Person
  {
    idnum  :: Integer,
    height :: Integer,
    weight :: Integer
  }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

-- *********************
-- *                   *
-- * data type: Person *
-- *                   *
-- *********************
instance ToJSON Person
instance FromJSON Person

-- **************************
-- *                        *
-- * data type: AfterPerson *
-- *                        *
-- **************************
data AfterMarathonPerson =
  AfterMarathonPerson
  {
    person     :: Person,
    weightLoss :: Integer
  }
  deriving (Show, Generic)

-- **************************
-- *                        *
-- * data type: AfterPerson *
-- *                        *
-- **************************
instance ToJSON AfterMarathonPerson

-- *******************
-- *                 *
-- * marathon effect *
-- *                 *
-- *******************
marathonEffect :: Person -> AfterMarathonPerson
marathonEffect (Person i h w) = AfterMarathonPerson (Person i h w) (w-23)

-- ********************
-- *                  *
-- * main entry point *
-- *                  *
-- ********************
main = do
  marathon <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String [Person])
  case marathon of
    Left jsonReadError -> putStrLn jsonReadError
    Right runners -> encodeFile "output.json"
      $ toJSON
      $ map marathonEffect
      $ runners
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`encodePretty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-pretty-0.8.9/docs/Data-Aeson-Encode-Pretty.html#v:encodePretty) function from the `aeson-pretty` package to produce a `ByteString` of pretty-printed JSON and then write it to file with `ByteString.writeFile` instead of using `encodeFile`.

Comment: thanks ! I'm new to Haskell so I still can't get the `encodePretty` to run properly. After a `cabal install aeson-pretty` I get this error: `Could not load module ‘Data.Aeson.Encode.Pretty’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘aeson-pretty-0.8.9’.`

Comment: OK I got it, turns out I needed to explicitly add the package in the command line: `ghc -ihaskell -O2 -package aeson-pretty haskell/Driver.hs -o haskell/Driver`. Thanks ! works perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't your project have a `.cabal` file? The correct solution is to add `aeson-pretty` as a dependency there.

Comment: actually no, this is literally my first haskell project so I'm using a makefile to manage compilation [: flushed-face-emoji-here :]